# how can I merge or split repeated data in Dataframe based based on it matches?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

where the name and the id is repeated, some information change, and I want to keep all in a single row.

```
Responsable Id  First Name  Last Name   Homephone   Workphone   Email
1               Sally       Sharrick
100             Angela      Beale                   9153426011  Angela.beale@gmail.com
100             Angela      Beale       3055881122  3052435552  Angela.beale@gmail.com
100             Angela      Beale       3055881122  9153426011  Angela.beale@gmail.com
100             Angela      Beale       3055881122              michael.beale@gmail.com
1000            Ayishah     Robinson    7707454800
1000            Ayishah     Robinson    7707454800              ayishah.robinson@yahoo.com
10000           Jennifer    Bacotti     3057267672              jenifer.bacotti@gmail.com
10001           Monica      Plata       3056081805              monica.plata@gmail.com
10003           Martin      Ravila
10004           Martin      Rovira      7862034321
10004           Martin      Rovira      7862034321              martin.rovira@gmail.com
10006           Cesar       Hernandez   3059875822              cesar.hernandez@gmail.com
10008           Alvaro      Garrido     7863881770              alvaro.garrido@gmail.com
10008           Alvaro      Garrido     7863881770              Alvaroh.garrido@gmail.com
10008           Alvaro      Garrido     7863881770  7863881770  alvaro.garrido@gmail.com
```

I want to join the reapeated information for the same person and create a new column for those different.
something like this:

```
Responsable Id  First Name  Last Name   Homephone   Workphone   Workphone 2 Email                       Email 2
1               Sally       Sharrick
100             Angela      Beale       3055881122  9153426011  3052435552  Angela.beale@gmail.com      michael.beale@gmail.com
1000            Ayishah     Robinson    7707454800                          ayishah.robinson@yahoo.com
10000           Jennifer    Bacotti     3057267672                          jenifer.bacotti@gmail.com
10001           Monica      Plata       3056081805                          monica.plata@gmail.com
10004           Martin      Rovira      7862034321                          martin.rovira@gmail.com
10006           Cesar       Hernandez   3059875822                          cesar.hernandez@gmail.com
10008           Alvaro      Garrido     7863881770  7863881770              alvaro.garrido@gmail.com    Alvaroh.garrido@gmail.com
```

I have tried with:

```
search_data = search_data.groupby(['Responsable Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name'], as_index=False).agg(" ".join)
```

but this conserved the repeated information.

and

```
search_data = search_data.groupby(['Responsable Id', 'First Name', 'Last Name'], as_index=False).first()
```

but it only merge this first element it find

any help is aprecciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided outputs for both of your attempts to solve the problem